# Fatal error: Call to a member function rowcount() on a non-object on a working query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running this query

```
try
{
$park_id = $_GET['park_id'];
$query2="SELECT `name` FROM  `tpf_rides` WHERE  `park_id` = $park_id AND  

`top_ride` = 1 ORDER BY `name` ASC";
$result2 = $pdo->query($query2);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$output = 'Unable to pull rides.';
include 'output.html.php';
}

$output = 'Sucessfully pulled rides';
//include 'output.html.php';//
```

and displaying it with

```
<?php foreach ($result2 as $row2): ?>

<li><h3><?php echo $row2['name']; ?></h3></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This all works fine and the list of 'top rides' displays correctly.

The issue is I'm trying to add an if statement so that if a particular 'park' has no 'top rides' that part of the page is not shown. Below is the code I'm trying to make work but I get the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function rowcount() on a non-object in /home/danville/public_html/parkindex/park.php on line 133" this bieng line 133 "if ($count2 = $query2->rowcount() < 1)" Can anybody help?

```
if ($count2 = $query2->rowcount() < 1)

{
    echo "No results found";
} 

else 

{
 echo "<h2>Top Attractions</h2>";

foreach ($result2 as $row2){

echo "<li><h3>{$row2['name']}</h3></li>";

}


}
```

Comment: i don't get the question, if your query already states `top_rides = 1` why would you handle records with no top rides?

Comment: @Fabio - It's a question about no results being returned by the query, not about handling results that don't match the where clause

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem. It turns out that the fix was to prepare, then execute.

```
$result = $pdo->prepare($query2);
$result->execute();
$count = $result->rowCount();
```

Strangely, rowCount is a function of the object returned from $pdo->query();, It seems like an internal glitch.

Try:

```
var_dump(get_class_methods($result));
```

to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Get the rowcount of the **result**, not of the query string

```
if ($count2 = $result2->rowcount() < 1)
```

not

```
if ($count2 = $query2->rowcount() < 1)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I still get the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function rowcount() on a non-object in /home/danville/public_html/parkindex/park.php on line 133". I've been tinkering for ages on this and can't work out why it wont work. Would it help if I posted the whole php page?

Comment: It might help if you posted line 133, and the few lines around it where you build and execute the query; but most people won't be willing to wade through a mass of code

Comment: I had to post it as an answer to fit it all so you should fine the more of the php code below as a answer

Answer (score 0):

there is something that is not logic in my opinion. If you already have `$park_id` and you match one specific row so to handle the result to appair only if `top_rides` = 1
so i would change query as follow

```
$query2="SELECT `name`, `top_rides` FROM  `tpf_rides` WHERE `park_id` = '".$park_id."'";
```

So now we are ready to place `if` condition and show only result wich has `top_rides` 
I assume this field is set to `1` when park has top rides.

```
foreach ($result2 as $row2)
{
    if($row2['top_rides'] == '1')
    {
         echo '<li><h3>'. $row2['name'] .'</h3></li>';
    } 
    else
    {
         echo "No results found";
    }
}
```

you will have to change yuor query to get `park_top` field as well so

```
$query2="SELECT `name` FROM  `tpf_rides` WHERE  `park_id` = $park_id AND  `top_ride` = 1 ORDER BY `name` ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where all my queries run for the page. the query in question here is query2

```
<?php

try
{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=danville_tpf', 'user',
'password');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$output = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
include 'output.html.php';
exit();
}


$output = 'Theme Park Database initialized';
//include 'output.html.php';//

try
{
$park_id = $_GET['park_id'];
$query="SELECT * FROM tpf_parks WHERE park_id = $park_id";
$result = $pdo->query($query);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$output = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
//include 'output.html.php';//
}

$output = 'Sucessfully pulled park';
//include 'output.html.php';//

foreach ($result as $row)
{
$parkdetails[] = array(
'name' => $row['name'],
'blurb' => $row['blurb'],
'website' => $row['website'],
'address' => $row['address'],
'logo' => $row['logo']);
}

try
{
$park_id = $_GET['park_id'];
$query2="SELECT `name` FROM  `tpf_rides` WHERE  `park_id` = $park_id AND  

`top_ride` = 1 ORDER BY `name` ASC";
$result2 = $pdo->query($query2);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$output = 'Unable to pull rides.';
include 'output.html.php';
}

$output = 'Sucessfully pulled rides';
//include 'output.html.php';//

try
{
$park_id = $_GET['park_id'];
$query3="SELECT `url` FROM  `tpf_images` WHERE  `park_id` = $park_id ORDER 

BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result3 = $pdo->query($query3);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$output = 'Unable to pull image.';
include 'output.html.php';
}

$output = 'Sucessfully pulled image';
//include 'output.html.php';//


?>
```

This is where the results should show

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($result2 as $row2): ?>

<li><h3><?php echo $row2['name']; ?></h3></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<hr>

<?php

if ($count2 = $results2->rowcount() < 1)

{
    echo "No results found";
} 

else 

{
 echo "<h2>Top Attractions</h2>";

foreach ($result2 as $row2){

echo "<li><h3>{$row2['name']}</h3></li>";

}


}

?>
```

line 133 is now `if ($count2 = $results2->rowcount() < 1)`